# Golang - RabbitMq : channel/connection is not open

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I'm new to golang, and I would like to refactorate my code so that the rabbitmq initialization is in another function that main. So I use a struct pointer (containing all the rabbitmq infos initilized) and pass it to the send function, but it tells me : Failed to publish a message: Exception (504) Reason: "channel/connection is not open"

struct :

```
type RbmqConfig struct {
    q amqp.Queue
    ch *amqp.Channel
    conn *amqp.Connection
    rbmqErr error
}
```

the init function :

```
func initRabbitMq() *RbmqConfig {

    config := &RbmqConfig{}

    config.conn, config.rbmqErr = amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(config.rbmqErr, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer config.conn.Close()

    config.ch, config.rbmqErr = config.conn.Channel()
    failOnError(config.rbmqErr, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer config.ch.Close()

    config.q, config.rbmqErr = config.ch.QueueDeclare(
        "<my_queue_name>",
        true,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    failOnError(config.rbmqErr, "Failed to declare a queue")

    return config
}
```

main :

```
config := initRabbitMq()

fmt.Println("queue name : ", config.q.Name)

sendMessage(config, <message_to_send>)
```

in send message :

```
func sendMessage(config *RbmqConfig, <message_to_send>) {

    config.rbmqErr = config.ch.Publish(
        "",           // exchange
        config.q.Name,       // routing key
        false,        // mandatory
        false,
        amqp.Publishing{
            DeliveryMode: amqp.Persistent,
            ContentType:  "text/plain",
            Body:         []byte(<message_to_send>),
        })
    failOnError(config.rbmqErr, "Failed to publish a message")
```

If someone has any idea, that would be very helpful. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inside your `init`, you wrote `defer config.conn.Close()`, which will be executed when the function return. That is to say, whenever `init` finished, your connection will be closed, which causes unopen connection.

You need to defer the connection closing in main, or somewhere you want it to be closed.

Comment: I know its good practice to close the connection, but just out of curiosity, what happens if I don't close it

Comment: I had the same issue, basically the name of the exchange should not be the name of the queue